# How to skip certain text while allowing selection for surrounding text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, textselection

For example:

```
<div class="example">
    <span class="selectable">foo</span>
    <span class="unselectable">bar</span>
    <span class="selectable">hello</span>
    <span class="selectable">world</span>
</div>
```

When performing mouse selection from 'foo' to 'world' (a sentence or paragraph), I want the selected text to be `'foo hello world'` with `'bar'` skipped. How this may be accomplished?

The css trick `user-select: none` doesn't seem to work for this purpose.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do what you're attempting.

Comment: Is it possible to get all mouse selected elements (rather than a text string), so that I can filter out unwanted elements, and then get the final text?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my answer, and I think it's working while selecting text, please take a look